# Authentication & Authorization via Data Annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have a database table that holds all of the users that should be allowed generic access to my application.  In addition to that, there is a bool column called `IsAdministrator` and if that is true, then that user is allowed access to specific actions/views like creating new users.. deleting existing.. etc..

My goal is to create a way so that if a user tries to access a create action/view when not being an administrator it returns them to the Error View Page.

I know I could do something like this:

```
    public ActionResult Personnel()
    {
        // get user who is logged in
        var personLoggedIn = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1]; // Intranet application.. so the domain name comes before the username hence the split

        if(_context.UserTable.Single(x => x.UserLogon == personLoggedIn).IsAdministrator == false)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }

        // more code below
    }
```

I was wondering if instead of copying and pasting this into each different actionresult.. I could put this into a data annotation and decorate each different actionresult with that data annotation?

**UPDATE**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using AuthorizeAttribute = System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class AdministratorsOnly : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public AdministratorsOnly() { }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {

        var personLoggedIn = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];

        using (var _context = new ConnectionStringName())
        {
            if (_context.UserTable.Single(x => x.UserLogon == personLoggedIn).IsAdministrator == false)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
        }


        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not an `AuthorizeAttribute` instead of an `DataNotation`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking into that now.. can I use that and it will work together with my database values? Do I have to override it to meet my requirements?

Comment: Sure, you will just need to use somekind of Dependency Resolver to access the instance of your `_context` inside the Attribute class

Comment: @MatheusCuba understood.  Not strong on dependency injection.. anyway you could post an answer?

Comment: Sure! Working on that, I just wanna to make sure that you would be open minded to another approuch

Comment: @MatheusCuba absolutely.  Anything is better than the way I was thinking of doing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not an `AuthorizeAttribute`?

This way, **all** requests to your controller are gonna have to passe through the `OnAuthorization` method.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class AdminOnlyAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute 
{
    public AdminOnlyAttribute(){

    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) 
    {
         //Here you will to figure out to 
         //have to access your Context with some DependencyResolver

         //Exemple
         var _context = ISomeInterface.ReturnCurrentContext();

         var personLoggedIn = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1]; // Intranet application.. so the domain name comes before the username hence the split

         if(_context.UserTable.Single(x => x.UserLogon == personLoggedIn).IsAdministrator == false)
         {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/PathToErrorView")
            //Or even
            filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "You don't have Access")
         }

         base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }         
}
```

Override the `OnAuthorization` method, and it would be called on all the Requests made on your Controller

Then use like this:

```
[AdminOnly]
public class MyController {
    [...]
```

Comment: If it is `void` how do I return bad request?

Comment: I'm getting red lines under OnAuthorization saying `no suitable method for override`

Comment: Are you inheriting your class from `AuthorizeAttribute`?

Comment: Oh I realized, your class must be on your WebProject aside your controllers. Because you must be using `System.Web.Mvc`

Comment: So, just put this class in my Controllers folder?

Comment: Not especific on your controllers folder, just anywhere on the Web folder of your project. Eg Generally in my project I put this kind of code in a folder called _Attributes_ that is the same level that the _Controllers_ one. But yes, if you put on your Controllers folder is gonna work too

Comment: updated my question again.  I created an Attributes folder and moved the class to that folder.. that folder is on the same level as controllers.  still same error

Comment: Might have to do with using statements and which namespace your attributeclass is defined on

Comment: You have to use the `System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute` not the `System.Web.AuthorizeAttribute`

Comment: I'm trying to redirect to a view in my shared folder.. any idea how to do this? I tried `filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Shared/NotAuthorized.cshtml");`, but that is giving me 404

Comment: @M12Bennett It's because `RedirectResult` need's the path of the controller of your _NotAuthorize_ not the **actual** path to your view. If you don't have one, just create one

Comment: So I need a controller for this? I can't just redirect to a view that is in my Shared folder?

Answer (score 3):

Something along these lines should do it:

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Error"); //Change "~/Error" to be the path to your error view
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var personLoggedIn = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];
        if (_context.UserTable.Single(x => x.UserLogon == personLoggedIn).IsAdministrator == false)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
        else
        {
            this.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you would use `[CustomAuthorize]` before the relevant methods/classes.  Also, you would need to make sure to initialize your _context variable.

Comment: Giving me a reason for the downvote would be helpful. Did the answer not work? Was it not verbose enough?  If I'm given information I can work to fix it. That being said, I realized there was a mistake in the answer that I believe I have corrected, so hopefully that was the reason for the downvote. Let me know if otherwise.

Comment: Nvmd fixed it.  Using System.Web.Http and not System.Web.Mvc

Comment: I'm wondering if your error is because of using statements and the namespace that your authorize attribute is defined on

Comment: @M12Bennett Where is this error occurring?  Have you tried putting `using System.Web.Mvc;` at the start of the file?

Comment: In my update I posted all using statements.  but for some reason the last one is where the AuthorizeAttribute was coming from.. strange.. erased it

Comment: Thank you for your help!